# Device to play media

Tags: video

Is there a machine i can buy that has a usb slot and hdmi output with a simple OS that I can use to reproduce media in various formats (introduced with a USB, formats like OOG,MKV,AVI,MP4,FLAC.APE etc?).

I was thinking something like raspberry pi but more powerful. In case I have to build one myself. What would a good OS be?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Vizio Co-Star](http://www.vizio.com/costar/overview) would likely be perfect (or any Google TV device, for that matter). It's based on Android (Google TV), and there are a number of great players available in the Play Store to play pretty much any format you throw at it...so as long as the apps are compatible, you'll be fine.  VLC is available in beta already, and will probably make its way to the market relatively soon...I'm guessing they'll work on making it available for set-top players.  Currently, MX Player is a good video player, and there are a number of audio players that will play most audio formats you throw at them.  Again, I don't know what is available to/compatible with the Co-Star or other set-top boxes, but I would guess that most apps in the Play store are available.